# List of Objects filled with Arrays asList doesn't compile requires List of Serializable

Tags: java, arrays, object, generics

Here is example code what I'm trying to do I'm trying to make a List of Object's of any mixed type boolean array's/int array's/long array's float array's/int's/long's/boolean's/Strings

```
public List<Object> saveState() {
return Arrays.asList("potatoes", false, 11, null, new int[] {123, 44}, new float[] {66.331, 11.22}, boolean[] {false, false, true});
}
```

```
  required: List<Object>
  found:    List<INT#1>
  where INT#1,INT#2 are intersection types:
    INT#1 extends Object,Serializable,Comparable<? extends INT#2>
    INT#2 extends Object,Serializable,Comparable<?>
```

Then when using real variables instead of hardcoding the values. I get this error

```
required: List<Object>
found:    List<Serializable>
```

I want to figure out how to convert a `new Object[] {...}` which compiles no problem but it has to be a List for another library I need to pass the values too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue with type inference comes when you pass different type arguments to a method that expects all the type arguments to be of same type. The compiler then infers the type parameter as intersection of all the common super types of your type arguments.

In your case, you are passing - `String`, `boolean`, `int`, `int[]`, so on... types. Of course they can't fit to a single type amongst all the types. So, the type inferred is:

```
Object & Serializable & Comparable<?>
```

As those are the super types of all the give types.

If you want you can explicitly specify a single type argument:

```
public List<Object> saveState() {
    return Arrays.<Object>asList("potatoes", false, 11, null, new int[] {123, 44}, new float[] {66.331, 11.22}, boolean[] {false, false, true});
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [Why doesn't type argument inference fail when I provide inconsistent method arguments?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ404)